# How to improve this Dynamic Programming solution?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Original problem statement [Pile it up](https://icpcarchive.ecs.baylor.edu/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=2338)

Summary: Two player A and B play a game consisting of 2 piles of X and Y coins. Each turn he can do one of the following:

- Remove any number of coin from a single pile (at least 1 coin)
- Remove the same amount of coin from both pile
- Pass the turn. This still count as one turn.

The game ends when no move is possible and the player who cannot make a move loses. Both players play optimally. Both players calculate the outcome of the game before the game begins. The player who loses tries to maximize the number of turns in the game and player who wins tries to minimize the turns. No player can pass more than P times. A starts the game. Output the name of the winner and the number of moves in the game separated by a single space. 0 <= X, Y, P <= 1000

I came up with an O(n^3) DP solution but surely it is not good enough for this problem considering the bounds. Let d[i, j] be the minimum number of turns to win if this is your turn to play and there are i and j coins left in pile X and Y respectively. Then we have:

```
d[i, j] = 0 if i = j = 0
          1 if (i = 0 && j > 0) or (i > 0 && j = 0) or (i = j && i > 0)
          min(min(d[i-p, j]), min(d[i, j-q), min(i-r, j-r)) if a each substate is a losing position
          max of all winning position substate if no losing substate is found
```

Finally, `d[i,j] = d[i,j] + 2*P if [i,j]` is a winning state and you will not win immediately from the start.

As you can see from the formulation above, this is a O(n^3) solution. I want to improve my solution to O(n^2), how can I reformulate the problem?

Comment: The “aim of this game” paragraph doesn't make sense; please edit question and fix it.  You probably mean *player A* where you wrote *winner* and *player B* where you wrote *loser*.

Comment: @Aravind:i and j are the remaning number of coins in pile X and Y.

Comment: why not the winner take all coins on the 1st chance?

Comment: @jwpat7: I updated the question, hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @sowrov: according to the game rules, you can only take coins from one pile or the _same number_ of coins from both piles. Thus, if X and Y are different you cannot win the game in 1 move.

Comment: Ok lets say, winner will take min(two of two piles) on 1st go thus only one pile left, loser will take only 1 coin then winner will take everything

Comment: @sowrov: if he does so, the second player to move will take whatever remaining of the nonempty pile and win, hence he will not _lose_. Therefore the first person to move will not make such a move, rather he will figure _how to win_, or _how to delay_ the victory of the other.

Comment: can you provide the link of the original problem?

Comment: @sowrov: Edited, I now include the link in the question.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the passing of turns seems like something that can be removed without changing the game. If any player gets into a losing position, (s)he will want to pass the turn. So, whenever a player gets into a losing position, each player will pass P turns and the game will continue as normal.

Comment: @Dukeling: its correct.

Answer (score 1):

First winning positions are

1. 1 empty pile
2. two piles with same number of coins

When will a player pass his turn?
Suppose position is (3,2), then thre are 3 options for him.

1. He can move to (2,2) but that makes it a winning position for his opponent.
2. He can move to (1,0) but again that is a winning position for his opponent.
3. If he chooses to skip the turn, then opponent can skip the turn too.This skipping can go for P turns at most.

Depending on parity of P(whether P is even or odd) and depending on who starts the skipping sequence, we can find out the person who won.Finding the number of turns isn't much harder from there.
**Why is the skipping sequence optimal?**
Well if you are losing you would want to stay in the game longer.(As given in rules of the game.)So even though I know based on the parity of P that I am going to lose, I can delay it by P turns.Make sense?
I encourage you to use this insight into making your algorithm faster, but please do ask questions if you have trouble implementing it!

Comment: Thanks @aravind. However I want to make it clear that P is _not the total number of passes allowed in the game_, each player can pass at most P time (so in the game there are at most 2*P passes). I figured that if the next move will lose the game, both player will use all of his P passes since no one want to lose. My primary concern is that there are 1000*1000 state and to fill each state we have go through 1000 substates, and this is way too slow.

Comment: @MinhPham: Do you really have to go to all 1000 substates? Nope, realize that if you are at (p,q) where p>q then, you will go to either (p-1,q) or (p-2,q) or (p-q+1,1) or to (p-q+2,2).If you are winning you want to win quickly, if you are losing lose slowly.If you are winning, move greedily to another winning position for you.If you are losing employ either the turn pass or move slowly so that you don't lose quickly.It's harder than I initially thought of.With some additional analysis, maybe you could solve it.Nice question BTW!

Comment: Can you explain why we will to only those 4 states? I understand the idea that you want to win quickly and lose slowly but I can't understand the choice of the 4 states.